# Is identically distributed and uncorrelated sequence a white noise?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

A white noise is defined to be a stationary process with constant power spectral density.

Is a sequence of random variables, which are identically distributed and uncorrelated, a white noise?

Is there a sequence of identically distributed random variables which is not  a stationary process?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your second question, a stationary process is one whose joint probability distribution doesn't shift with respect to time. If a sequence of variables is identically distributed, it's joint distribution must not shift with respect to time! This is equivalent to saying that its statistical moments are invariant in time.

Regarding your first question, it depends on your definition. According to the signal processing definition, the answer is yes. An [i.i.d.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iid) random variable is white noise, by definition.

Comment: Thanks! (1) For the first question, the sequence of random variables are not iid, but identically distributed and uncorrelated. Is it a white noise? (2) The sequence of random variables is identically distributed, only meaning the marginal distributions of each random variable are the same. Can you give an example that it is not stationary?

Comment: @Tim Of course, uncorrelated does not necessarily imply independent! (Don't know why I thought that's what you meant). There are almost certainly times when variables are uncorrelated but not independent and do not create white noise. Simply find two dependent random variables with zero covariance. ($y=x^2$ would likely not be white noise -- I haven't worked through the proof, so that's just my hunch). As far as non-stationary, technically wide-sense stationary processes fit the bill.

Comment: (1) Does  "identically distributed" and "uncorrelated" imply a white noise? (2) Is there a sequence of  identically distributed random variables always which is not a stationary process? (not in wide-sense)